# Открыть Facebook messenger (если установлен) или Facebook.com (если не установлен)

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Требуется открывать ссылку в facebook messenger (если это приложение есть),  либо страницу в facebook в браузере (если приложение не установлено либо мы переходим по ней с компьютера). Ссылка переводит на сообщение конкретному человеку.

Код для facebook messenger выглядит так:

```
fb-messenger://user-thread/userid
```

Код для facebook выглядит так:

```
https://www.facebook.com/messages/userid
```

Если мы ставим первый вариант, не срабатывает открытие ссылки в facebook в браузере, если второй - использование facebook messenger. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
try {
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/<id_here>"));
}
catch (Exception e) {
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
```

}
}

К сожалению не знаю, как можно вызвать диалог, чтобы открывать либо с браузером, либо с приложением.